# Text appears as black dots in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: windows-7, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I was trying to a edit a PDF with Adobe Acrobat XI Pro on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate:

[image]

The PDF is a figure that was generated by the Python library [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), which apparently use the  Bitstream Vera Sans Roman font by default.

I downloaded the font from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/bitstream-vera-sans and installed it:

[image]

It works fine in Microsoft Word 2013:

[image]

It can see the font listed in Adobe as well:

[image]

However, when I type some text using this fond, the text appears as a series of black dots:

[image]

Also if I try to edit the text I was just trying to modify, I get the error message:

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Any idea is welcome.